# how to get last inserted id on button click and should be display in html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

Need to get the last inserted id from database on button click...after the button click there will be a new page ...on this page i want to print last inserted+1 means next id...please help me.

```html
<a href="index.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">ADD MEMBER</button></a>
```

Comment: You should use ajax, Try at your end first and come if not you get any problem

Comment: While doing insert query you can easily get last inserted id by built-in function, but the way which you want, you can do:-`SELECT id from <table> ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Anant's idea is beyond terrible. Don't use an autoincremented ID for a public key. This id should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its simple `mysqli` has its built in `function` for this

after successfull `insertion` just call this `function`

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

}
```

or As mentioned in comments you can also run `query` to get `last inseted id`

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {  

  $result= mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT id FROM Table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$last_id = $row['id'];

    }
```

Comment: i m using pdo mysql not mysqli

Comment: public function getlastid()
{
      $return = false;
    $sql = "SELECT  `id` FROM  `member_entry` ORDER BY  `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result)
        {
        $return =true;
        }
        return $return; 
}

Comment: i m using this function...and calling to index.php as <p class="left">
            <label for="member_id">MEMBERS No.:</label>
            <?php  echo $view=$obj->getlastid();?>
          </p>

Comment: hey look it should be just after saving data in database. Do one thing whenever you save a data in database just save last insert id into a variable and echo where you want

Answer (score 0):

$result= mysqli_query("SELECT * from tablename where id='".mysqli_insert_id($conn)."'");

Reference link: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php